How to set sensitive properties with `ControllerApi.create_controller_service()`?
I've tried the following:
generate_controller_service = controller_service_api.create_controller_service(
    body=nipyapi.nifi.ControllerServiceEntity(
        parent_group_id=root_id,
        revision={'version': 0},
        component=nipyapi.nifi.ControllerServiceDTO(
            name=controller_service_name,
            bundle=nipyapi.nifi.models.bundle_dto.BundleDTO(
                group='org.apache.nifi', 
                artifact='nifi-aws-nar',
                version='2.0.0-M4'
            ),
            type='org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService',
            properties={
                'Access Key ID': 'ABC'
            }
        ),
    )
)

However, this creates a new property Access Key ID rather than setting the existing property value.

The correct property is:
properties={
    'Access Key': 'ABC'
}

I found this by using the browser network inspection tools, and editing an existing controller service.  I could see the property name in the request json.
